# Compare two columns and copy paste using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns in a sheet "test". Let's assume col C and D.

Each rows in C and D might have either "COMPATIBLE" or "NOT DETERMINED" or Blank cell.

I want to compare col C and D,and if C has "COMPATIBLE" and D has "NOT DETERMINED", then "COMPATIBLE" should be paste into D and vice versa.

I have below code, But not sure how to complete it:

```
Sub compare_cols()

'Get the last row
Dim Report As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer

Set Report = Excel.Worksheets("test") 'You could also use Excel.ActiveSheet _
                                        if you always want this to run on the current sheet.

lastRow = Report.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 2 To lastRow
    For j = 2 To lastRow
        If Report.Cells(i, 1).Value = "COMPATIBLE" Then 
            If InStr(1, Report.Cells(j, 2).Value, Report.Cells(i, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0
```

UPDATING THE WORK IN PROGRESS CODE:

```
Option Explicit

Sub compare_cols()
With Worksheets("Latency") '<-.-| reference your worksheet
    With .Range("F1:G" & .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row) '<--| reference its columns C:D range from row 1 down to worksheet last used row
        Correct .Cells, "COMPATIBLE", "Not Determind", 2
        Correct .Cells, "Determind", "COMPATIBLE", 1
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub

Sub Correct(rng As Range, val1 As String, val2 As String, colToChangeIndex As Long)
With rng '<--| reference passed range
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=val1 '<--| filter referenced range on its 1st column with 'val1'
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=val2 '<--| filter referenced range on its 2nd column with 'val2'
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any filterd cells other than header
        .Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).Offset(1, colToChangeIndex - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "COMPATIBLE" '<--| write "COMPATIBLE" in column "D"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is that all the code? ...you need to close your `If` and `For` statements, first of all.  What have you tried?  And finish the second `If` statement...

Comment: Yes I'm stuck with this. I'm not sure how to close it and complete the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `AutoFilter()`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub compare_cols()
    With Worksheets("test") '<-.-| reference your worksheet
        With .Range("C1:D" & .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row) '<--| reference its columns C:D range from row 1 down to worksheet last used row
            Correct .Cells, "COMPATIBLE", "NOT DETERMINED", 2
            Correct .Cells, "NOT DETERMINED", "COMPATIBLE", 1
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub

Sub Correct(rng As Range, val1 As String, val2 As String, colToChangeIndex As Long)
    With rng '<--| reference passed range
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=val1 '<--| filter referenced range on its 1st column with 'val1'
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=val2 '<--| filter referenced range on its 2nd column with 'val2'
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any filterd cells other than header
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, colToChangeIndex - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "COMPATIBLE" '<--| write "COMPATIBLE" in column "D"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't want to write "Not Determined" I just want to write "COMPATIBLE. and the code is not working..it runs, but i dont see any results

Comment: 1) in your question you wrote _""COMPATIBLE" should be paste into D and vice versa."_. now you say something different: please add examples of a "before" and "after" scenarios to clarify 2) code acts on worksheets and ranges as per comments: check if they fit your actual worksheet name and ranges:  adding the beforesaid "scenarios" would help

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant was  if C has "COMPATIBLE" and D has "NOT DETERMINED", then "COMPATIBLE" should be paste into D and if C has "NOT DETERMINED" and D has "COMPATIBLE", then "COMPATIBLE" should be paste into C. Example here - [link](https://ufile.io/ff72b)

Comment: Just a doubt in `With Worksheets("test")` - I have a workbook and I need to run this code in a sheet named "test"...so that's what this code does right?

Comment: if you have only one workbook open then it suffices. if you have more than one workbook than add the proper workbook reference like `With Workbooks("MyProperWorkbookName").Worksheets("test")`

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here...Still the code doesnt do anything..I have uploaded my file and code here - [link](https://ufile.io/54e551) - can you please take a looo and tell what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry but I wouldn't download any file from the web and especially macro enabled ones! You can link relevant shots of your examples in your question

Comment: Can i attache screenshot links?

Comment: Yes. Images cannot do any harm! But be sure to post only minimal (in number and extension) shots to reproduce your "environment"

Comment: I have uploaded the image at [link](https://ufile.io/146b0). This shows the my excel sheet. (NOTE: the cols are F and G and i was just using C and D as examples)

Comment: then change columns indexes from C and D to F and G and watch for typos (in your post you wrote "NOT DETERMINED" while in your pics there's "not determind". If this solves your question please mark answer as accepted thank you!

Comment: I'm the sorry one for you. in my tests everything works. Have you changed `"C1:D"` to `G1:D"`, and "NOT DETERMINED" to "not determind" (or, viceversa, change in your sheet "not determind" to "NOT DETERMINED")?

Comment: I have edited the OP with the code that i'm trying....for your refernce

Comment: in your edit the second call to `Correct` still has a "Determind", instead of a "Not Determind"

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMMMMGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG!!!!!!!!!! FINALLYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY......YOU ARE AWESOMEEEEEE

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Sub CvalueAndDvalue()
    Dim cValue As Range, dValue As Range

    Dim Report As Worksheet
    Set Report = Excel.Worksheets("test")

    For i = 2 To Report.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set cValue = Report.Range("C" & i)
        Set dValue = Report.Range("D" & i)

        If (Trim(cValue) = "COMPATIBLE" And Trim(dValue) = "NOT DETERMINED") Then
            dValue = cValue
            ElseIf (Trim(dValue) = "COMPATIBLE" And Trim(cValue) = "NOT DETERMINED") Then
            cValue = dValue
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: added qualified ranges

Comment: In what format should i specify the range? Lets say I need to check in both the cols from rows 1 to 100

Comment: the code will check both columns C and D, until the last row in column C. I don't understand what you mean by "In what format should i specify the range"